# Syntax error using sys.argv as argument in function

Tags: python, sys

Got syntax error caused by this line of code

```
def load(sys.argv):
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        reader = json.load(file)
        return reader['json']
```

Message from stderr:

```
    def load(sys.argv):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Of course, I have imported sys.

Actually, parameters inside the function, that use sys.argv, work properly. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You could define a parameter that you pass sys.argv to, but can't you define a parameter *named* sys.argv.

Answer (score 1):

Functions pass in parameters and variable names, you don't declare them in there. You code should look like the following

```
def load(arguments):
    # Your Code
    firstArg = arguments[0]

load(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sys.argv` as a function argument.
Just rename the argument and it will work:

```
import sys
def load(args):
    # your logic

print(load(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to specify you want sys.argv[1] inside the function, you wouldn't need any sort of parameter. You could make it a function that needs no arguments.

```
import sys

def load():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        # code to execute...
        # code to execute...

load()
```

My suggestion is only applicable if you only want to open one file using one command line parameter (at index 1). If you wanted to open others using other command line parameters, you would need a parameter in your function like 'args' (like David Teather said) to make the code more flexible. 
Parameters are set as new variable names to be used within the scope of your function. In your code, it's like you are trying to set 'sys.argv' as a function name, which doesn't work because it is already a function.